# How to perform Manual step in JMeter and resume test

Tags: jmeter

Can I perform a test that will stop in some step, and after I perform something manually in my system I will tell Jmeter to resume running the test?
is it possible in JMeter to pause a test in the middle and then to resume it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about out of the box solution in JMeter, so you need to add such logic yourself.

For example you can do a [While controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) with a variable set to true at start, inside loop read from file until it's value is false and then exit loop and resume test. You can even use [StringFromFile](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) function as `${__StringFromFile(flagResume.txt,,,)}`

In your manual operations add to file the value false, and then the JMeter test will resume.

Answer (score 0):

What is the nature of the task you need to do manually? I'm pretty much sure that it is doable via JMeter itself, [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) or [Groovy Scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

---

If I'm wrong or you have a very specific scenario one of possible solutions would be adding [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to your Test Plan and define desired `Requests per Minute` rate using JMeter Property via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Whenever you need to "stop" the test you can set the "throughput" property to `0` using i.e. [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)